# Sum the contents of many dropdowns when any of them change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have several dropdowns on a page, and they all contain some numbers. When the user change any one of these, I need to go through all of them and sum all the numbers.

How would I do that with jQuery?

```
<select id="number1">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="number2">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="number4">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

I've tried something like:

```
$('select[id*="number"].change(function() { // when any one dropdown change

    $('select[id*="number"].change(function() { // go through them all
        var current = $(this);

        // add current value to array
    });
});

$.each(arr,function() {
    total += this; // sum items
});
```

But it doesn't quite work as expected. Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: Is the missing single quote in the two selectors a typo on here, or?

Comment: And the missing parentheses too?

Comment: No, that's actually my bad! I'm so sloppy without a proper editor. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be trying to nest calls to `change()` inside each other. Don't use `change()` the second time, use `.each()`. (Also you were missing a closing `')` at the end of each of your selectors so your code wouldn't work at all.)

It doesn't make sense to loop through an array outside the `change()` handler, because when would that code actually run?

Try this:

```
$('select[id*="number"]').change(function() { // when any one dropdown change
    total = 0; // reset the total
    $('select[id*="number"]').each(function() { // go through them all
        total += +this.value; // use unary plus to convert string value for addition
    });
    // do something with total here
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/8L9Hz/

Comment: You're welcome. Note that this code needs to be wrapped in a document ready handler (unless it is included at the end of the body after the elements in question). Also unless you have a good reason to make `total` global you should probably define it locally within the change handler - I've left it as a global in case you are using it elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aDzHB/1/) out.

javascript code

```
  $(function(){
     $('.my_number').change(function(){
       var sum = 0;
       $('.my_number').each(function(){
          sum = sum + parseInt(this.value);
       })
     $("#result").html(sum);
  })

})
```

HTML code

```
<select class= "my_number" id="number1">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select class= "my_number" id="number2">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select class= "my_number" id="number4">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but i went with the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be using `Array.prototype.reduce` to sum the values

```
var selects = $('select[id*="number"]');
selects.change(function () { // when any one dropdown change
    var total = [].reduce.call(selects, function (l, c) {
        return l + ~~c.value
    }, 0);
    console.log(total)
});
```

*Note the compatibility though. You'd have to use a [shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Browser_compatibility) to support older browsers*

Heres a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fMCfm/1/)